# Systemd: Using both After and Requires

Tags: linux, redhat, systemd

I have a service `foo.service` which depends on service `bar.service`. I need to make sure that `bar.service` is started before `foo.service` and that `bar.service` launched successfully.

From [this source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) it says that `Requires`:

> This directive lists any units upon which this unit essentially depends. If the current unit is activated, the units listed here must successfully activate as well, else this unit will fail. These units are started in parallel with the current unit by default.

and that `After`:

> The units listed in this directive will be started before starting the current unit. This does not imply a dependency relationship and one must be established through the above directives if this is required.

Is it correct to have both the `Requires` and `After` sections in the same unit file? `Requires` says that the service will be launched in parallel, but `After` says it will be launched before. If `bar.service` fails to start during the `After` condition, will it attempt to launch it again during the `Requires` section? If so I need to find another way to launch `foo.service`

`foo.service`

```
[Unit]
After=bar.service
Requires=bar.service
```

Comment: Using both `Requires` (or `Wants` for that matter) and `After` should be what you're looking for. That enforces the order (`After`) and the dependency (`Requires`). It won't launch it again "during the `Requires` section" (note as well that service files are not executed but parsed).

Comment: @Whymarrh okay so I assume that means having both directives will change the "default" startup mentioned in the `Requires` description; "started in parallel with the current unit by default"

Comment: Yes, see also: [`Requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use both `After=` and `Requires=`. They have different purposes. `Requires=` sets up a start dependency. systemd makes sure that if any body is trying to start foo.service, it should start bar.service too. Should bar.service fails at some point, then foo.service is taken down too.

`After=` is putting a start order between services. If both of the services are scheduled to start, then `After=` makes sure the start order is set.

You can look at systemd's own service file as an example.

```
/lib/systemd/system/basic.target
[Unit]
...
Requires=sysinit.target
After=sysinit.target
...
```

Comment: what about WantedBy?

in 
/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/watchdog.service: 
[Unit]
After=multi-user.target
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Answer (score 14):

While Umut's answer is correct, there is an interaction between `Requires=` and `After=` that is rarely spelled out. From [systemd.unit#Requires=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) (emphasis is mine):

> If this unit gets activated, the units listed will be activated as well. If one of the other units fails to activate, *and an ordering dependency `After=` on the failing unit is set*, this unit will not be started.

Essentially, this means that without `After=`, both services will be started if `foo.service` is started (because of `Requires=`), but systemd will not stop `foo.service` if `bar.service` does not start successfully.

However, with the added `After=`, it will wait for `bar.service` to start successfully (with some exceptions; see the note in the `Requires=` docs) before it starts `foo.service` and won't start it if `bar.service` doesn't start.

Somewhat related is the difference between `Requires=` and `BindsTo=` (see the docs around the link above).